# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Error While opening Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, exception, excel-interop

I am getting "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" error, from the following call:

```
this.currentWrkBook = this.application.Workbooks.Open(fileNameExcel);
```

Information:

> - Windows 7, MS Excel 2010
> - fileNameExcel is excelMacro.xlsm
> - Path file: D:\Data\excelMacro.xlsm
> - Excel file is closed when executing

Google searches seem to be suggesting that this is a version match error. However, my machine uses Excel 2010.

Any suggestions would be very welcome. Thanks in advance.

My code is here:

```
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application application { get; set; }
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook currentWrkBook { get; set; }
private string currentFileName { get; set; }

public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook openWorkBook(string fileNameExcel)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook rtn = null;

    try
    {
        this.currentWrkBook = this.application.Workbooks.Open(fileNameExcel);
        this.currentFileName = fileNameExcel;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message); 
    }

    return rtn = this.currentWrkBook;
}
```

Comment: In which language version of Excel is the File created? Excel in different Languages behave different in automation.

Comment: What you talked about is version of **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** ?

Comment: No, the language of your installed Office Package...

Comment: The language of my installed Office Package is Japanese (`Language Pack x64 : 10.0.50903`, `Ms Office Plus 2010 : 14.0.7015.1000`)